Cannot import better-sqlite3 in javascript file
I'm currently trying to import a module called better-sqlite3 into a javascript file for a database project I have coming up. When I run npm run in the command line everything works fine. I even see the database file being made. However, when I try to view the webpage in the browser I get the following error.
Uncaught TypeError: The specifier “better-sqlite3” was a bare specifier, but was not remapped to anything. Relative module specifiers must start with “./”, “../” or “/”
I'm really unsure as to what is going on, I install the module using the npm install command and it does show up in my node_modules folder in my projects root directory. I currently have my javascript file as type module in the package.json file. Any help would be appreciated.
Also, this is how I am importing the module import Database from 'better-sqlite3'

import is only used for node.js.  In a browser, you use a <script> tag to load Javascript modules.  Remember, the browser isn't running on your computer.  It doesn't have access to your files, unless you load then with tags.

Hi, thanky you for your response. Can I get an example of this? I'm very new to node js and JavaScript so I'm not sure how to exactly implement your solution. Thank you.

First, let me make sure what I said applies.  Are you running a webserver written with node.js?  Or are you loading this code into a browser? Do other imports work?

@TimRoberts that isn't really true: in modern ESM JS, only your main script gets loaded with a <script> tag, and everything else is normal import statements in your code instead. However, the real question is "why would the browser need to load sqlite?" You should only need that on the server side, you're not sending the entire database over to the client are you?

Not only can you use import in a browser, there are libraries (JS, TS) to run SQLite 100% in the browser, but better-sqlite3 is not one of them.
